# Setting base file path when doing simple Templating with Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2, templating

I am using Jinja purely for creating template.
Here is the scheme I have:

**page1.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}

    <div class="container">
        <img src="./images/{{svg_name}}" style="padding-top:100px; padding-left:100px" align="center" width="60%" heig
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/sticky-footer-navbar.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="../images/favicon.ico">

        <title>MY TITLE</title>

    </head>
    <body>


 <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">Adjuvant</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:foo@yahoo.com">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- End navbar -->


        <!--- BEGIN INSERT TEMPLATE FOR OTHER PAGE  HERE-->
        {% block 'body' %}

        {% endblock %}
        <!--- END TEMPLATE FOR OTHER PAGE  HERE-->



    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted"> &copy; 2015 &middot;  
     </p>
      </div>
    </footer>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../src/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="../src/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../src/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>




    </body>


</html>
```

**code_to_make_template.py**

```
from jinja2 import Template, FileSystemLoader
from jinja2.environment import Environment
env = Environment()
env.loader = FileSystemLoader('.')


template  = env.get_template("htmls/src/templates/page1.html")
output_string = template.render(svg_name=filename)
```

The directory structure looks like this:

```
 current_dir
   |___ code_to_make_template.py
   |___ html
         |_ src
             |_ templates
                  |_ base.html
                  |_ page1.html
```

But when I run `code_to_make_template.py` I got this message:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: base.html
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Hm, try this: `template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'html/src/templates')`
|
`jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = True)`

Comment: @Kris: Yes it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'html/src/templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = True)

def render_str(template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        return render_str(template, **params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))
```

Then you just inherit that class in your rendering classes and do:

```
class PageOne(MainHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.render('page1.html')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/page_one', PageOne)
                               ],debug=True)
```

Comment: I find this solution is too long for such simple OP problem.